# Nested Loops in SQL with SELECT Statements with Python

Tags: python, mysql, loops

new to programming and trying to figure out an assignment. I have to do a nested loop with only select statements (no join statements) with Python. At a bit of a loss as to how to do so.

The following is the code I've been using. But keep getting an error where they say the name course_no is not defined.

Sorry in advance if this is a n00b question!

```
query = ("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM instructor")
query2 = ("SELECT course_no, section_no FROM section")

try:
    cursor.execute(query)

    print("Result set returned")

    for (first_name, last_name) in cursor:
        print(first_name + " " + last_name)

        for (first_name, last_name) in cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT course_no, section_no FROM section")
            print(course_no + " " + section_no)
    cursor.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: Why not to use a nested query with only in sql?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says first_name and last_name are not defined. The values are coming through in the form of tuples so you can access by the index value

```
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0],row[1]) # first_name, last_name
```

Also you need to get the results saved in a variable for

`cursor.execute("SELECT course_no, section_no FROM section")`

Also do not name `cursor` twice

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question as best as I can understand it.
course_no is indeed not defined as it is enclosed in cursor. Try looping through the cursor again but this time for course_no and section_no. Also I suggest that you use a different cursor for each query as on the next loops the cursor no longer has the values of the external loops. Showcasing some code:

```
try:
    cursor1.execute(query)

    print("Result set returned")

    for (first_name, last_name) in cursor1:
        print(first_name + " " + last_name)

        cursor2.execute("SELECT course_no, section_no FROM section")
        for (course_no, section_no) in cursor2:
            print(course_no + " " + section_no)
        cursor2.close()
    cursor1.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
```